# SDL W8 Name must be unique for items of type: Component within this Folder and its BluePrint context. Source or sources of conflict:

Tags: web8

I created new folder and created first component inside the folder. i got this error in SDL Web8.1. i just want to where can i fixe this issue.

Name must be unique for items of type: Component within this Folder and its BluePrint context. Source or sources of conflict: tcm:182-128830.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It`s sdl web 8 code issue in FieldsContainer.js file.

Problem description: 
Saving Component with multiple embedded RTF will execute save multiple times

Answer (score 2):

The error is fairly clear... You named your component identically to another existing item in the same folder either in the current Publication or one of it's children. The existing item's ID is tcm:182-128830. You will either need to change your chosen name for the new component *or* find tcm:182-128830 and change it's name (including the name of any localised versions) before trying again.

If this was genuinely a completely new folder, perhaps you created 2 components by mistake or perhaps there is some automation code at work to cause the naming conflict?

Comment: Thanks for info. it`s new folder and creating first component inside the folder.

Comment: Well that sounds _very_ strange. If it's a new folder then I fail to see how there could be an item with the same name. Can you try changing the name of your new item? Does that work around the error? Is the error reproducible? In another location?

Comment: If you want to re-produce this issue in SDL W8. Please try below steps.

Step1: create Embeddable Schema 

Embeddable Schema


Name: _Emb_TEST
Schema Type: Embeddable Schema
Root Element Name : Test_content


Design:


XML Name : question
Type     : Text
Mandatory:yes
Enable for inline editing:Yes
Translatable: Yes

Height of the Text Area 2 Row
Allo Rich text Formatting:Yes


XML Name : snswer
Type     : Text
Mandatory:yed
Enable for inline editing:Yes
Translatable: Yes

Height of the Text Area 5 Row
Allo Rich text Formatting:Yes

Comment: Step2: Content Schema:

Name: TEST
Schema Type: Schema
Root Element Name : test

Design:

XML Name : test_content
Type     : Embedded Schema
Mandatory:yes
Enable for inline editing:Yes

Embedded Schema : _Emb_TEST
Allow Multiple Values : Yes

Step3: Create new component using TEST schema.
Step4: Enter content then click SAve and close button.